# Is there a conversion factor between Android sampling frequency (Hz) and sampling period (µs) (HIGH_SAMPLING_RATE_SENSORS)

Tags: java, android, sensors, android-sensors

I'm retrieving sensor data by using
`mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mLinearAccelerometer, SAMPLINGPERIOD)`

Android 12 introduced a rate-limitation on sensor data. If you call the registerListener() method, the sensor sampling rate is **limited to 200 Hz**. If your app tries to gather motion sensor data at a higher rate without declaring the new permission **HIGH_SAMPLING_RATE_SENSORS**, a SecurityException occurs.

Now, I'm a little bit confused because in registerListener, we have to define the sampling period **in µs and not in Hz**.

If I'm using values for SAMPLINGPERIOD < 5000, the abovementioned exception occurs:
**java.lang.SecurityException: To use the sampling rate of 4999 microseconds, app needs to declare the normal permission HIGH_SAMPLING_RATE_SENSORS.**

Does this mean that a sampling rate of 200 Hz is equivalent to a sampling period of 5'000 microseconds used in registerListener? Or is this sensor-dependent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST requires the new HIGH_SAMPLING_RATE_SENSORS permission. The other constants don't require it. If your code uses a flexible integer definition as SAMPLINGPERIOD, you'll need the permission as soon as you go below 5'000 µs.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, I've just found the answer: 5'000 µs are 0.005 seconds, i.e. we have 200 events per second (1/0.005), i.e. 200 Hz.

Comment: I just wonder is how do the SENSOR_DELAY_* constants behave with these changes. 200 Hz is quite fast, so I'd say that SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, SENSOR_DELAY_UI and SENSOR_DELAY_GAME should not trigger a SecurityException and require the HIGH_SAMPLING_RATE_SENSORS permission. Only the SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST should require it IMHO. But we will have to test this out since it is undocumented.